# Best way to load balance MQTT is cluster or Bridge and why

Tags: mqtt, load-balancing, emq

One or more MQTT brokers could be bridged together. Bridge forward PUBLISH message from one broker node to another. [1]

Clustered nodes will share/copy the same topics tree, but bridge nodes will not.

What is the protocol used to share the same topics tree in a cluster ?
Is it HTTP ?
is it disadvantage ? Because MQTT is a light weight protocol compared with HTTP

1. https://github.com/emqx/emqx/wiki/Bridge

Answer (score 0):

Erlang/OTP, TCP communication between clusters.
Best way is using cluster.

```
                              ----> Node1
                              ----> Node2
-----> Nginx/HAProxy/AWS SLB  ----> Node3
                              ----> Node4
                              ----> Node5
```

Comment: This answer needs a LOT more context to be useful.